# Preserve spaces in html links for operating system call arguments

Tags: html, hyperlink, spaces

I built a html index page for German *rtp iptv* broadcast addresses which works very well, you can look at it here:
http://lan7even.homenet dot org/Server7even/test/iptv.php

For those links to work one have to have a german Telekom Entertain dsl/vdsl connection and one have to register the `rtp://` protocol handler in the browser to call *vlc* media player.

There I already configured one argument for vlc to open in minimized view which works as well.

Now I am trying to set an additional argument which has to be different for each link: the iptv stream title (channel name)

But spaces are replaced by the browser with %20 automatically and therefore vlc does not recognize the argument.

Everything I find are informations about the known stuff to preserve spaces in html for display purposes, but I can not find anything to alter the space substituting behavior when called via html link.

Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are not valid characters in URLs. From the [URL Standard](http://url.spec.whatwg.org):

> The URL code points are ASCII alphanumeric, "!", "$", "&", "'", "(", ")", "*", "+", ",", "-", ".", "/", ":", ";", "=", "?", "@", "_", "~", and code points in the ranges U+00A0 to U+D7FF, U+E000 to U+FDCF, U+FDF0 to U+FFEF, U+10000 to U+1FFFD, U+20000 to U+2FFFD, U+30000 to U+3FFFD, U+40000 to U+4FFFD, U+50000 to U+5FFFD, U+60000 to U+6FFFD, U+70000 to U+7FFFD, U+80000 to U+8FFFD, U+90000 to U+9FFFD, U+A0000 to U+AFFFD, U+B0000 to U+BFFFD, U+C0000 to U+CFFFD, U+D0000 to U+DFFFD, U+E1000 to U+EFFFD, U+F0000 to U+FFFFD, U+100000 to U+10FFFD.

You'll need to handle %20 appropriately on the server side.

Comment: What if there is no server side? Remember: I call a local binary.

Comment: Just had an idea: call an intermediate script that does back-decoding with the launch of vlc binary afterwards. This would work but implies more configuration on each computer using those links.